# check if the right radioButton is checked and calculate the score

Tags: android, android-intent, radio-button

i have an android application that display a flag and group of radio buttons  that each time the user check any radio button the application will  display a button that allow to go to the next page using intent .

what i need is that each time the user check the right answer the system must calculate its score until the application finish .
the score will start by 0/0 and will finish after four rounds.

**for now i need just to display the score of the user in the second page**

i will appreciate any help

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.flagology;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnS;
    RadioGroup rdgS;
    RadioButton rdS1, rdS2, rdS3, rdS4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rdgS = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdg1);
        rdgS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(rdS1.isChecked()||rdS2.isChecked()||rdS3.isChecked()||rdS4.isChecked()){
                     btnS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 }
            }
        });

        rdS1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s1);
        rdS2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s2);
        rdS3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s3);
        rdS4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s4);

        btnS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_s);
        btnS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String input;
                String result = null;
                Double dbl;

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
               switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.rd_s1:
                input = rdS1.getText().toString();
                dbl  = Double.parseDouble(input);

                i.putExtra("score", 0);
                break;
            case R.id.rd_s2:
                i.putExtra("score", 0);
                break;
            case R.id.rd_s3:
                i.putExtra("score", 25);
                break;
            case R.id.rd_s4:
                i.putExtra("score", 0);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.hint_icon:
            ShowAlertDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.about_icon:
            Toast.makeText(this, "developed by Georges Matta",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void ShowAlertDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Hint")
                .setMessage("The famouse sport is Bullfighting")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

## edited code

```
rdS1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s1);
        rdS2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s2);
        rdS3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s3);
        rdS4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_s4);

        btnS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_s);
        btnS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String input;
                String result = null;
                Double dbl;

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                switch (rdgS.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.rd_s1:
                    input = rdS1.getText().toString();
                    dbl = Double.parseDouble(input);
                    result = String.valueOf(dbl);

                    i.putExtra("score", result);
                    break;
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/spanish" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Gess the Country of the flag"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#CCFF99" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rdg1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd_s1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Egypt"
            android:textColor="#CCFF99" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd_s2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="China"
            android:textColor="#CCFF99" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd_s3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Spanish"
            android:textColor="#CCFF99" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd_s4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:text="Italy"
            android:textColor="#CCFF99" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_s"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rdg1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rdg1"
        android:text="Next"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## SecondActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.flagology;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt_result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        txt_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("score");
            txt_result.setText(value);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## activity_second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: Use an intent to send the score to the second activity?

Comment: the problem is that how to calculate the score and how to show it in the second activity using intent

Comment: @user3006788 look at my post below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to modify your `switch` case as follows:

```
...
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
switch (rdgS.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.rd_s1:
        input = rdS1.getText().toString();
        dbl  = Double.parseDouble(input);

        i.putExtra("score", 0);
        break;
    case R.id.rd_s2:
        i.putExtra("score", 0);
        break;
    case R.id.rd_s3:
        i.putExtra("score", 25);
        break;
    case R.id.rd_s4:
        i.putExtra("score", 0);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

startActivity(i);
...
...
```

After this since your are passing in `int` values, you should use `getInt()` method. In your oncreate of `SecondActivity` do this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = String.valueOf(extras.getInt("score"));
    txt_result.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: @ Amulya khare  i   did change the code as you say check the question but still did not work

Comment: @user3006788 You changed more things than I asked. Now you have some `result` String which is being parsed and all.. can you do what you did previously and see if it works? change back to `i.putExtra("score", 0);` etc etc..

Comment: Also, I have copied and compiled you original code with my solution.. works like a charm :) so please make sure you are following what I have said very carefully

Comment: okk thank you now it work. now if i want to calculate the score that each time the user check the right answer how to do it ??? like i will add each time 25 to have the final score over 100 ??

Comment: in each activity declare a private field `int score`. In the `onCreate()` set the value of score = last activity score (that you get from bundle.). Then in the switch case, update the `score = score + <0, 25 or whatever>` and pass to next activity. For more detailed answer maybe you should move to a new question. This one is already talking about some other problems..

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
        intent.putExtra("showResult", result);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This should match `extras.getString("score");` string in the second activity, so change it to:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", result);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: my bad i did copy the wrong chunk of code now i fixed see the question  sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick(View v)` handler, `v` refers to the button `btn_s`, therefore `switch (v.getId())` will not work since `v.getId()` will always return id of the button, i.e. `R.id.btn_s`.

You need to query states of the radio button separately, for example use

```
if (rdS1.isChecked()) {
    // first ratio button is checked
} else if (rdS2.isChecked()) {
    // second is checked
} else if ...
```

Replace your `switch (v.getId())` in `onClick(View v)` with that `if`.

Comment: Ignore my original comment about making `RadioButton`s final. This is not the case, since they are members of your Activity.

Comment: so what i need to do as you say i need to check if the radioButton is checked ???

Comment: inside your `onClick()` implementation, yes